# Removing generic nulls from a mixed list in kdb

Tags: kdb

I have a function that returns a mixed list. This list has generic nulls which I am looking to remove as I am not able to raze and eventually get a table.

```
q)sample
  ::
  ::
  (+(,`hostName)!,,`hostName1)!+(,`topCpu)!,,0f
  ::
  (+(,`hostName)!,,`hostName2)!+(,`topCpu)!,,0f
  (+(,`hostName)!,,`hostName3)!+(,`topCpu)!,,0f
  (+(,`hostName)!,,`hostName4)!+(,`topCpu)!,,0f
  ::
  ::
  ::
```

I tried using except keyword but that didn't help either

```
q)sample except ::
k){x@&~x in y}[(::;::;(+(,`hostName)!,,`hostName1)!+(,`topCpu)!,,0f;::;(+(,`hostName)!,,`hostName2)!+(,`topCpu)!,,0f;(+(,`hostName)!,,`hostName3)!+(,`topCpu)!,,0f;(+(,`hostName)!,,`hostName4)!+(,`topCpu)!,,0f;::;::;::;
```

Is there any effective way of removing these?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `brackets` to wrap it up with `except`

```
q)0N!sample:(::;::;([hostName:enlist`hostName1] topCpu:enlist 0f);::;([hostName:enlist`hostName2] topCpu:enlist 0f))
(::;::;(+(,`hostName)!,,`hostName1)!+(,`topCpu)!,,0f;::;(+(,`hostName)!,,`hostName2)!+(,`topCpu)!,,0f)
::
::
(+(,`hostName)!,,`hostName1)!+(,`topCpu)!,,0f
::
(+(,`hostName)!,,`hostName2)!+(,`topCpu)!,,0f
q)sample except(::)
(+(,`hostName)!,,`hostName1)!+(,`topCpu)!,,0f
(+(,`hostName)!,,`hostName2)!+(,`topCpu)!,,0f
```

Comment: `enlist` is not needed. But brackets are ```q)(::;1;::;2;::;3) except (::)``` otherwise a composition is created.

Comment: Ah interesting. Didn't know that. I've updated with your comment.

Comment: The above works due to order - to make it robust, would need something like `{(y,x)except y}[2_ sample;::]`
match is more robust again as Rian suggested originally

Answer (score 1):

```
q)(::;1;::;2;::;3) except (::)
1 2 3
```

You need brackets, otherwise the trailing `::` makes a composition out of the statement

- https://code.kx.com/q/ref/compose/
- https://github.com/quintanar401/DCoQ?tab=readme-ov-file#mystery-of-